# I can't ask a question

Tags: bug

I asked 4 questions here, **no one is negative**. I deleted 1 , with positive grading, long ago because I got no answer.

Is there something wrong with the database? If I try to ask a question, every day it tells me to wait 'just one more day'. Can you fix that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any way to tell whether this is a bug or not, as the algorithm for question blocks is not public. Your account was blocked from asking a question about 12 hours ago, but it is not currently blocked. As you say, you've asked 4 questions, with 1 deleted, but the deleted question actually does have a negative score. I don't know whether you still have access to the question as it was deleted several months ago. I can link to it if you'd like to see for yourself, but you can also confirm this by the fact you've earned the [peer pressure badge](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=646). With that said, one deleted negative-scoring question is not normally enough to trigger a block so I'm fairly surprised that you were blocked here. In any case, so long as you maintain a positive record from here, you shouldn't get blocked from asking again.